# Mongoid 5 + Devise + Rails 4 - User not able to sign in

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, mongoid

I have upgraded my mongoid to version 5 and using below

`rails 4.1.4`

`devise 3.5.6`

When i try to login a user, the user is signed in but when it redirects to `dashboard#index` it is not logged in, means session is lost.

My logs are as

```
Started POST "/campaign_managers/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-02 22:33:34 +0530   
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lkrl4znSHibTgjLwcw/xiBC5SAbZm1gtBDGczhiomE0=", "campaign_manager"=>{"email"=>"ashishtest@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Submit"} 
MONGODB | Adding localhost:27017 to the cluster. 
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | my_development_db.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"email"=>"ashishtest@gmail.com"}, "limit"=>1, "singleBatch"=>true}

MONGODB | localhost:27017 | my_development_db.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.0007080480000000001s 
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | my_development_db.update | STARTED | {"update"=>"users", "updates"=>[{"q"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('569337f369702d0459180000')}, "u"=>{"$set"=>{"last_sign_in_at"=>2016-03-02 16:53:31 UTC, "current_sign_in_at"=>2016-03-02 17:03:35 UTC, "sign_in_count"=>91}}, "multi"=>false, "up...
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | my_development_db.update | SUCCEEDED | 0.000398332s

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 194ms

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-02 22:33:35 +0530

Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML

MONGODB | localhost:27017 | my_development_db.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"_id"=>nil}, "limit"=>1, "singleBatch"=>true}   
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | my_development_db.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.00038932400000000003s

Completed 401 Unauthorized in 7ms
```

So if you see the next time it tried to create the session, the `_id` is found nil because of which it goes to login page again.

I have tried many solutions available on google but nothing worked for me.

Please help if anyone has idea of mongoid 5 with devise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did it work before? What's you session store? You don't have a custom session controller, right? Your browser does have cookies enabled?My money is on the session storage.

Comment: With Mongoid 3 everything was working fine but just after upgrading to version 5 , user login stopped working.

Comment: Do update th mongoid 4 first. Also make sure to update your mongodb server. I'm still on mongoid 4 for my own app as I fear various gems not being compatible yet.

Comment: i just check that my previous mongid version was already 4.0.0.